# What's a good, affordable "knob" library?

Tags: winforms, graphics, .net-2.0

I'm currently thinking of a new pet project, an "editor" for MIDI-enabled synths. I've got the MIDI side covered, I suppose, but what I'm looking for right now is something that can pass for nice "dials" and "knobs" like you see in Ableton Live, Reason, Reaktor, and so forth.

Putting my form full of trackbars, is sort of wasteful, y'know?

So, what is a nice affordable .NET 2.0 library that has that sort of graphical components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/industrial_controls.aspx has some related controls (C#)

2- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/desaijm/KnobControlusingWindowsForms11182005004925AM/KnobControlusingWindowsForms.aspx is another C# based Knob Control

Used the (2) personally on one project and it worked great (though not visually very strong). (1) looks cooler but havn't explored

Comment: I like the first one. The behaviour of the LBKnob may not be exactly what I need, but since it's free and the source is included, I might get by with some tweaking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this myself, but found [KineticaRT controls](http://www.kineticart.co.uk/KineticaRTKnob.asp). $67.06.

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.co.uk](http://www.kineticart.eclipse.co.uk/Products/KineticaRT/Images/KnobSplash.gif))</sub>

[GMSI.Net Knob v2.0](http://www.globalmajic.com/Net-Instrumentation-Controls-c11.html). $169.00.

[alt text http://www.globalmajic.com/mc_images/product/thumbnail/net_knob150.jpg](http://www.globalmajic.com/mc_images/product/thumbnail/net_knob150.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Check out some of these.  If none just do search for ".net gauges".  Most of the major UI control libraries have a gauge or dashboard library.

http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Product.aspx?lang=en&pid=44
http://www.brothersoft.com/software_developer/microsoft_.net/.net_dashboard_suite_56186.html
http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/GaugesSilverlight/
http://www.dundas.com/